# Centering when cropping pdfs with Briss

Tags: pdf

I use Briss to convert 6 per page pdfs to 1 per page. It works well but I cant get output pages to be centered (i.e the white border around each page is different from the other pages).

The output ends up looking like this:

[image]

Functionally there is no issue, but it just bothers me a little bit. Is there a way to get Briss to detect the black border around each page and crop it accordingly? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that works for me. Skim for OSX has a crop function that automatically centres the pdf pages.